# css drop down menu collapses

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-float

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tewm.png

my drop down menu goes under the next div element, any idea on how to fix this?

Css:

```
 .cf ul li{
float:left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style:none;
font-family:"open sans", sans-serif;

}

.cf li a {
display:block;
padding:0 1em;
line-height: 2.5em;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

.cf li a:hover {
background-color:#ffa627;
}


li{
position:relative;
}
ul.submenu {
float:none;
background: #222;
position:absolute;
left:-9000em;
}

.topmenu li:hover ul{
left:0;
}   

ul.submenu li {
float:none;
}

#nav-bar nav {
background-color: #222;

}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
content: " "; /* 1 */
display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;

.callout1 {
background-color: #fff; 
text-align: center; 
padding: 20px 0px;
width:319px;
text-decoration:none;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color:#222;
border-right: 1px solid #EFEFEF; 
float:left;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-bar" class="cf">
                <nav class="cf">
                    <ul class="topmenu">
                        <li class="hometop"><a href="#" class="hometop">Home</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#" >Catagory</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Blah Blah</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blah UGG</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li ><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">How To Order</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>
<div id="extra-info">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="callout1">Do You Have Any Questions? <br>Contact Us</a></li>
```

First time making a website, pulling my hair out, trying to figure out this all day now, quick one of you dev wiz help meh please!

Edited: have pasted the "do you have any question contact us" div html as well as its css.

Comment: use z-index http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: post the do you have any questions div code and its css too

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, added the z index to ul.submenu and it worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. I hope this CSS class should work

```
.cf{
   position:relative; 
   z-index:9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by putting greater z-index to dropdown

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

like

```
div{
  z-index:5;
}

.dropdown{
   z-index:6;
}


Note: z-index only works on positioned elements
```

(`position:relative , position:absolute, or position:fixed).`